# Whenever I want to start my Apache, below message is apperaring:

Tags: xampp

Attempting to start Apache app...
    Status change detected: running
    Status change detected: stopped
    Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
    If you need more help, copy and post this
    entire log window on the forums

Answer (score 0):

Your log will tell you exactly what you need to know. Proceed to:
cd /var/log/apache2